# Is it correct to say, “justification for and reference to your answer”?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, writing

I want to shorten the words “justification for your answer and reference to your answer” by saying, “justification for and reference to your answer”. Is this shorter form correct? If not, how should I say it?

Comment: A complete sentence would be helpful. I'm thinking an "in/with reference to..." might work better as a separate phrase or perhaps omitted. As is, I would use commas: *justification for, and reference to,...*

Comment: AS Djin implies, context is, as almost always, important. It's hard to see how the two concepts can be reconciled sufficiently not to need separate sentences or even paragraphs.

Comment: None of this sounds as if it has any meaning in English. It sounds as if you are attempting business babble. Please state simply what information you wish to convey and in what context. Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: What @David said. How would you refer to an answer's justification without making reference to that answer? Be brave and assume your own reply makes sense. Otherwise, you could ending up announcing your response as a response to a response, which should be clear from your content.

Comment: @David, I am wanted to ask a question on Physics SE, which I have [already asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656469/266420) by now. In addition to the answer that I will be getting, I wanted some explanation as to why something that the person is stating is true, which I referred to as justification. Also, I wanted some sources from the internet or books as references to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that this phrase sounds unnatural. You may say "justification and reference to your answer", without "for" in this case. Hope it helps :)